# Behaviour Difference: 'null' initialized final static member, and 'null' initialized final local variable

Tags: java, compiler-warnings, final, static-members, local-variables

I came across a behavior, I didn't knew of earlier, in the follow up code.

Consider the 1<sup>st</sup> case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    final String str = null;
    System.out.println(str.length());  // Compiler Warning: NullPointerAccess
}
```

As expected, the compiler shows me following warning on `str` being *null* - *Null pointer access:* The variable str can only be null at this location.

Now, when I moved that variable a *static final field* initialized to *null*:

```
class Demo {
    static final String str = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(str.length());  // No Compiler Warning
    }
}
```

Now, compiler doesn't show any warning. AFAIK, Compiler should know that `str` being final, will not change its value, at any point of the code. And given that it is `null`, will definitely result in `NullPointerException` later on, which it does.

Although, compiler successfully warns me of this in the first case, why it cannot identify this in the 2nd case. Why this change of behaviour? The behaviour is same, if I change `static` field to `instance` field, and access it using an instance of `Demo`.

I thought this behaviour might have been specified in JLS, so I went through the topic *Definite Assignment*, but didn't find anything related to this issue. Can anyone explain the change in behaviour? *I'm looking for some strong point with some link to JLS if possible?*

Apart from that, why compiler shows me only *warning* in the first place, as I think for the same reason I stated above, the method invocation will definitely throw *NPE* at runtime, since the field can't be changed? Why didn't it rather show me a Compiler Error? Am I expecting too much from compiler, as it seems to be quite obvious, that the runtime result of `str.length()` can't be anything than `NPE`?

---

Sorry for missing that earlier:

I'm using *Eclipse Juno*, on *Ubuntu 12.04* with *OpenJDK 7*.

Comment: The JLS doesn't *usually* go into details of warnings much - it's a compiler implementation detail. I wouldn't be surprised if some compilers *did* warn about this.

Comment: @JonSkeet. But I would expect any compiler to behave in the same way in both the case. In both the case, I'm accessing method on definite null reference.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to do so - but I'm saying that it's a matter of how far the compiler implementation wants to go. I wouldn't expect it to be in the JLS, and you don't say which compiler you're actually using.

Comment: @JonSkeet. Ah! sorry for that. Added it now. Hmm, well I am ok with JLS not going into much detail, and it wouldn't be possible too IMO, still a legitimate reasoning would be great.

Comment: What happens if you change the visibility of the `static final` field to `private`?

Comment: @chrylis. Wouldn't make a difference, as I'm accessing it from same class only.

Comment: But it might change the sort of inferences the compiler can make.

Comment: @chrylis. Doesn't change anything. It looks like it is with Eclipse Compiler only. When I compile with `javac -Xlint:all`, it doesn't show any warning, in both cases.

Comment: *sigh* The Eclipse compiler has some really odd corner cases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow! It turned out, it was eclipse specific issue. When I compiled the code using:

```
javac -Xlint:all Demo.java
```

it didn't show any warning for any case. So, I went back to eclipse to check any settings enabled for this case, and found one.

In *Windows* -> *Preferences* -> *Java* -> *Compiler* -> *Errors/Warnings*, under *Null Analysis*, I can change the way the *Null Pointer Access* should be treated by Eclipse Compiler.
I can set it to - *Ignore*, *Error*, or *Warning*.

And now it seems like a completely silly question. Shame on me. :(

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure in 100%, but in the second case where you have final field against local variable, there is possible assigns to this final field some value direct in static (or instance block depending if variable is static or not) initialization block:

```
class Demo {
...
static {
 str = "some text";
}
...
}
```

so compiler don't give you warn.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    final String str = null;
    System.out.println(str.length());  // Compiler Warning: NullPointerAccess
}
```

In this case str is a local variable and compiler will not compile if you try to perform any operations on it before  initializing it. Flow analyzing is altogether different, it will check the flow of the code in which it detect that at the point you perform the length() operation the local variable str can only be null.

```
class Demo {
    static final String str = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(str.length());  // No Compiler Warning
    }
}
```

In this case str is an instance variable and will be null even if you don't explicitly assign so.

Still why no warning here?

You could have initialize the instance variable in the constructor. Or you could call a setter method on it before calling the lenght() operation on it. So it escapes from the flow analysis(compiler is not sure whether the instance variable will be null at that point or not but in 1st case compile is sure that the local variable will always be null).

Comment: I would have buyed it in case of non-final fields, in which case, the behaviour is bound to be different in two cases. But given both are final variables, none of them can be changed after initialization. So, I cannot see how compiler cannot identify null access in one case, while it can in the other.

Comment: I think you didn't notice that the field is `final static`. You can't initialize it in constructor, neither in any setter?

Comment: Yeah did not see final there! I don't know exactly how flow detection works in java but I would guess it does not handle your case. If it would not have been static and just final it could be initialized in the constructor and if it would have been just static then in some static block. Your case is unique and I guess it is not handled.